# Coordinate separation and integrability

Tags: many-body

Why is a system of coupled harmonic oscillators analytically solvable, regardless of dimensionality or particle number, but if the system is coupled by 1/r potentials it is not?

I was used to think about this in terms of the number of conserved quantities, but this reasoning wouldn't apply to the oscillator (correct me if I'm wrong).

Furthermore, I've noticed that for classical and quantum systems as well, numerical approaches for n-body 1/r potentials use to converge to a result very close to the "experimental" one. As I see it this makes the issue closer to a more-than-fifth-grade-polynomial than to a underspecified system of equations. Thoughts on this, please.

Comment: in short: you are wrong, there is a tensorvalued conserved quantity for the n-dimensional oscillator.. i dont have access to a suitable reference at the moment, but you should be able to google that

Comment: In the Wikipedia article about the Laplace Runge Lenz vector they mention a conserved dyadic tensor. How do you write it for n arbitrary oscillators?